# ImportError: cannot import name start_ipython

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have extracted ipython-1.1.0.tar.gz in /usr/lib/ipython-1.1.0 and have run the following commands to finish the build and installation:

```
root@my-laptop:/usr/lib/ipython-1.1.0# python setup.py build
root@my-laptop:/usr/lib/ipython-1.1.0# python setup.py install
```

I am using Python 2.6 and is installed under /usr/bin/python2.6 and have my additional packages under /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/

Now, when I am trying to start ipython notebook from shell command, I am getting the following ImportError message:

```
root@my-laptop:/usr/lib/ipython-1.1.0# ipython notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 5, in <module>
  from IPython import start_ipython
ImportError: cannot import name start_ipython
```

When I tried to start the IPython instance as mentioned in README.rst file, I got the following message:

```
root@my-laptop:/usr/lib/ipython-1.1.0# python -m IPython
/usr/bin/python: IPython is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

I tried easy_install and pip install

```
root@my-laptop:/usr/lib/ipython-1.1.0# easy_install ipython
Searching for ipython
Best match: ipython 1.1.0
Adding ipython 1.1.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for ipython
root@my-laptop:/usr/lib/ipython-1.1.0# pip install ipython
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6
Installing collected packages: ipython
Successfully installed ipython
```

But the ImportError problem still remains unresolved. This is not allowing to open the interactive Python.

I found some solution in the below link, but not sure about it:

```
https://trac.macports.org/ticket/40119
```

Comment: is this mac or linux?  You have made quite a mess of the installation.  Typically you un-pack the source into your home directory and then install it _to_ /usr/.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04. I have downloaded the tar.gz under /home/<me>/Downloads and then extracted under /usr/lib/

Comment: I have installed from source instead of built-in package as I want to use numpy 1.7.0 and scipy 0.13.0 and the default package with Python 2.6 is numpy 1.3.0 and scipy < 0.10.0 which would does not support the scipy.optimize package

Comment: that is the source of your problems.  Remove everything you have added to `/usr`, unpack the tar to `~/ipython_src` in that directory run as root `python setup.py install`

Comment: and _never_ run python/ipython as root to do work

Comment: but in the first comment you mentioned to install to /usr/ and I have installed the additional packages under /usr/lib/. But I agree I should not have used root. But most of the online documentation refer using "sudo"

Comment: by 'install' I mean let the `python setup.py install` move stuff there for you, not do it by hand.

Comment: I did it that way only. I did tar xvzf ~/Downloads/####.tar.gz to /usr/lib/ and then ran `python setup.py build` and `python setup.py install` in the extracted dir

Comment: The problem is you unpacked the tar to where it is going to try to install.

Comment: "I have installed from source instead of built-in package as I want to use numpy 1.7.0 and scipy 0.13.0"   ---- Cant you use "easy_install numpy==1.7.0" and similar commands to replace the existing packages with the specific versions you want?

Comment: It appears to be finding an older installation of `IPython`. You'll need to remove that. The `python -m` trick doesn't work with Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem as well.  Are we sure the IPython API didn't change?  I got something that looks right working with:

```
import IPython
IPython.Shell.start()
```

edit:
ok, nvmind.  There was also another program I installed at the same time that decided to change PYTHONPATH.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import IPython
IPython.start_ipython()
```